# Sending constant parameters to change a model field in dukescript

Tags: dukescript

How can I send any parameter to change something in the model?

I tried with setters but failed, and when tried to do it from the view I got a strange behaviour.

This is as far as I'm now.

HTML:

```
Selected name: <span data-bind="text: selectedName"></span>
 <ul data-bind="foreach: names">
   <li> 
     <a data-bind="text: $data, click: $root.nameSelected" href="#"></a>
   </li>
 </ul>
<hr>
<a data-bind="text:'hi',click: $root.nameSelected('hi')" href="#"></a>
```

Java:

```
package dew.demo.namesmodel;

import net.java.html.json.Model;
import net.java.html.json.Property;
import net.java.html.json.Function;

@Model(className="Names", properties={
   @Property(name = "selectedName", type=String.class),
   @Property(name = "names", type=String.class, array = true)
 })
class NamesModel {
   @Function static void nameSelected(Names myModel, String data) {
     myModel.setSelectedName(data);
   }

   static {
     Names pageModel = new Names(
       "---", "Jarda", "Pepa", "Honza", "Jirka", "Tomáš"
     );
     pageModel.applyBindings();
   }
}
```

you can see the example running on this [fiddle](http://dew.apidesign.org/dew/#65416b30651ac41789fe).

Comment: What behaviour did you observe?

Comment: when running in dew you can see the word `hi`

Comment: can you send me the link?

Comment: also, any java log and javascript (Firebug) log would be useful, when I have time I'll build this page, it doesn't take long.

Comment: You can also check out Geertjan's example, to see if you can get them to work: https://github.com/GeertjanWielenga/DukeScriptSamples

Comment: Addeded code on `DEW`. No errors on log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to workaround the problem by using **with** binding:

```
<div data-bind="with: 'hi'">
  <a data-bind="text: $data,click: $root.nameSelected" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

as your [updated DEW](http://dew.apidesign.org/dew/#a083ada2ddd2a5ed3ee6) shows.

Answer (score 1):

The example seems to fail only in DEW. I created a normal DukeScript project, where it works fine, also when running in a browser. So I assume this is simply a bug in DEW.

Comment: DEW is using 0.8.3 version of HTML/Java - probably I should update it.